# ruby backticks redirection error

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, backticks

whenever I try

```
irb(main):008:0> `while read FILENAME; do echo "Hi";done < <(cat /tmp/a)`
```

I get the following error:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

Is there anyway to bypass this issue, but still use back ticks for the shell exec from ruby?

Comment: Can you show your script? Any references to bash there?

Comment: I think @Nobita is likely correct. ruby is almost certainly defaulting to using `/bin/sh` and not `bash` and that is the cause of your problem. You need to use `bash` (or some other non-`sh`) script explicitly.

Comment: I could use 'system', but I need the output as well.